# Catch some drug dealers

Tags: code-golf

**(spoilers on decade-old TV show below)**

In the HBO show "The Wire", the dealers use a system of encoding phone numbers where they "jump the 5" on the number pad.

```
+-----------+
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
+-----------+
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
+-----------+
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
+-----------+
| # | 0 | * |
+-----------+
```

A "1" becomes a "9", "4" becomes "6", etc ... and "5" and "0" swap places.  So, the input number 2983794-07 becomes 8127316-53.  # and * are undefined.  Input in the show was numeric with a dash, your code does not need to preserve the dash but it does need to accept it.  No real restrictions on how user interaction is handled, can be a function or console application as needed.

Scoring criteria:

This is a code golf, fewest characters wins.  There is a 100 character penalty for solving it with a number/character swap or array lookup (I'm trying to broadly paint a brush stroke to avoid `"9876043215"[i]`-style lookups).  10 character bonus for not stripping dashes.

Comment: Isn't *every* solution going to use number/character swap with or without a detour?

Comment: Maybe I should make it a pop-con question instead, to get creative answers out of it?

Comment: Isn't this just ten minus each digit? (Beside 5/0)

Comment: @insta Taking a simple task and saying "solve this creatively", generally makes for a *very* bad popularity contest.

Comment: Rats, well it seemed like it would have been a good challenge on the drive in :(

Comment: "There is a 100 character penalty for solving it with a number/character swap or array lookup." This is a vague and unenforceable rule. If your challenge has a boring optimal solution, you should rethink the challenge rather than try to ban that solution.

Comment: @MartinBüttner taking a simple task and linking it to not only drug dealers, but the illustrious "Wire" and you're generally bound to have a few happy people. Omar's coming

Answer (score 10):

## MATLAB, 25 bytes

Function accepting a string.

`-` is converted to `=`... so the dash is not just preserved, there is twice as much of it?

```
@(n)106-n-5*(n==48|n==53)
```

Comment: LOL twice as much :D

Comment: I think you need to add a few bytes. You need to convert the answer from int to char. I think the easiest way is: `f=@(n)['' 106-n-5*(n==48|n==53)]`. (Fewer bytes than `char(...)`.)

Comment: @RobertP. True, it will display numbers if you simply evaluate `f` on the command line, but it will work fine if used where a string is expected, e.g. `fprintf('%s\n', f('3259232352'))`

Answer (score 9):

### tr, 107 (17 + 100 - 10)

```
tr 0-9 5987604321
```

Comment: Perl port: `y/0-9/5987604321/` and `-p` flag. Run with: `perl -pe'y/0-9/5987604321/' <(echo 2983794-07)` Score is `17` + `1` + `100` - `10` = `108`.

Answer (score 8):

### GolfScript 9 (= 19 - 10)

```
{16|106\-.5%3=5*-}%
```

or

```
{16|~107+.5%3=5*-}%
```

[Online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OycxMjM0Njc4OS01MCcKCnsxNnx%2BMTA3Ky41JTM9NSotfSU%3D)

#### Explanation

As observed by a few people, this calls for subtraction of the digit from 10 in most cases. Since the digits in ASCII start at 48, that means subtracting the ASCII code from `48*2+10 = 106`. That leaves three special cases:

- `0` and `5`: these map to `10` and `5` respectively, and need to map to `5` and `0`. Solution: `.5%3=5*-` subtracts `5` if the result is equal to `3` modulo `5`.
- `-`: this is the fun one. ASCII code `45`, so equivalent to digit `-3`. After the reflection it's equivalent to digit `13`, so I need to subtract `16`. But I can equivalently do that by *adding* `16` before the reflection, and since `45` is the only relevant ASCII code not to have the bit corresponding to `16` set, I can accomplish that with a simple bitwise OR: `16|`.

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript, ES6, 27 bytes (37 - 10)

```
f=_=>_.replace(/\d/g,y=>y%5?10-y:5-y)
```

Try it in latest Firefox like

```
f("2983794-07")
```

Comment: Perl port: Run `s/\d/$&%5?10-$&:5-$&/ge` with `p` flag like this: `perl -pe's/\d/$&%5?10-$&:5-$&/ge' <(echo "2983794-07")` which would be 23 + 1 - 10 = 14 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, 13 (23 - 10) bytes

```
'-_l\/{{si_5%A5?\-}%}%*
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Answer (score 0):

## C (63 - 10 = 53)

```c
main(_){while(_=getchar())putchar(_>47?(_-=48)%5?58-_:53-_:_);}
```